# How can I download a tweeted image given the tweet id?

Tags: serviceexecute

`ServiceExecute[]` supports sending an image via "ImageTweet" i.e. posting an image in a tweet. But how can I achieve the reverse of this and download the image given the "TweetID"?

Comment: I don't see any possible options in `ServiceExecute` that could work. Have you tried making a custom function to download straight from the internet page of the tweet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure the internet used to be simpler than this! Anyway, this worked for the two examples I tried:

```
tweetid = "493792023691149312";

s = ServiceConnect["Twitter"];

tweet = ServiceExecute[s, "GetTweet", "TweetID" -> tweetid];

link = Last @ Flatten @ StringCases[StringSplit[tweet], "http" ~~ __];

manylinks = Import[link, "Hyperlinks"];

anotherlink = First @ Flatten @ StringCases[manylinks, __ ~~ "photo" ~~ __];

xmldata = Import[anotherlink, "XMLObject"];

finallink = First @ Cases[xmldata, XMLElement[
      "meta", {"property" -> "og:image", "content" -> address_}, {}] :> address, -1];

Import[finallink]
```